# <c:when test ---- Unable to parse EL function

Tags: javascript, jsp

whats wrong with this? the second condition causing issue. reason I am trying to get value by calling method.

`<c:when test="${(not empty abc.value1) && (user.getSec().getCode() == 'AA') }">`

please rewrite, how to accomdate the 2nd condition in this tag.

Comment: <c:when test="${(not empty student.marks) && (User.getEntity().getcode() == 'aa') }">               this is the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try (user.sec.code=='AA') 
that is -  do not use getters use the names of the properties instead.